# Manipulating MS Word Open Dialog from Delphi

Tags: vba, delphi, ms-word, dialog

Every time I run this code, I manually confirm that I want to convert "PDF Files".

Is there any way to automate it?

```
procedure TFWordAnalyzer.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Clipboard:TClipboard;
  WordApp,WordDocument: OleVariant;
begin
  try
    WordApp := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application') ;
 end;

  WordApp.visible := true;
  WordApp.DisplayAlerts := False;

  WordDocument := WordApp.Documents.Open('D:\Corpus\Adyg\Hudmir.pdf', true, false);

  WordDocument.range.copy;

          sleep(1000);//Otherwise it fails
          RichEdit1.Clear;
          RichEdit1.PasteFromClipboard;

  WordDocument.close;
  WordApp.Quit;
  WordApp := Unassigned;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to execute that part of the tasks you want to perform within word as a word vba macro (e.g. by recording the steps via macrorecorder). This prevents using sleep statement that might fail in case of readinf the pdf takes too much time and does not show that dialog. The recorded macro you can execute either via commandline by WINWORD.EXE /mMacroName or via ole by calling Application.Run('Normal.Module1.MacroName')

Comment: Good point. I may try it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the problems you have mentioned namely how to avoid the Convert File dialog and the pop-up prompt about saving data copied to the Clipboard can by avoided by specifiying the correct values in calls to Word's automation.

**1.  Avoiding the Convert File dialog**

Update the line of your code which opens the document to

```
WordDocument := WordApp.Documents.Open('D:\Corpus\Adyg\Hudmir.pdf', ConfirmConversions := False);
```

This should open the document without the Confirm Conversion dialog being invoked.

Assuming that works, you should be able to reinstate your second and third arguments, so that you have

```
WordDocument := WordApp.Documents.Open('D:\Corpus\Adyg\Hudmir.pdf', true, false, ConfirmConversions := False);
```

Note that the syntax

```
WordApp.Documents.Open([...], ConfirmConversions := False)
```

was added at the same time (in D2) at the same time as OLE automation via OleVariants, to support optional arguments being passed to automation calls.

PS:  With this change, you may find that your call to Sleep in unnecessary.  I say "may" because my test code did not need it in the first place.

**2.  Avoiding the prompt to save the contents of the Clipboard.**

This prompt pops if you attempt to close Word using automation when you have copied a large amount of data to the Clipboard.

To avoid it, simply replace

```
WordApp.Quit;
```

by

```
WordApp.Quit(SaveChanges := False);
```

That should be all you need.  The fact that this works is slightly counter-intuitive:  As you saved the data from your WordDocument, you might expect that using WordDocument is the way to clear the Clipboard data (see the now-superfluous **update** below).  However, by setting up a test app with a number of checkboxes which control the parameter values for WordDocument.Close and WordApp.Close, and testing the various permutations of their settings, I established that only the value of SaveChanges passed to WordApp.Quit influences this behaviour and avoids the dialog (if it would otherwise have been displayed).

The remainder of this answer can be disregarded but I have let it remain aas it may help future readers with similar problems.  I have also added the **VBA** tag to the q, as I found numerous questions about how to avoid the Clipboard-save prompt in VBA questions, but none with a definitive solution which worked with the code here.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Update** The OP reported that the above code can result in a prompt from
Word as it closes down saying that there is a large amount of data on the Clipboard,
and queried whether it was possible to automate responding to the prompt.

Google found several suggestions for avoiding the prompt, but I found that none
of them worked reliably working with a 17Mb .Pdf file.  The method shown below,
which I arrived at by experiment, *does* seem to work reliably but is not as simple
as I would like it to be.

The reason the prompt occurs is that Word evidently sets up internal pointers to
the contents provided to the Clipboard, so I wondered if setting the text of the
Range to something much smaller and then discarding it before closing the document
would work.  I ran into 2 problems:

- calling vRange.End := 1 had no effect
- trying to call vRange.Set_Text := ' ' provoked an exception claiming that vRange
  does not support the Set_Text method despite the fact that the Range interface in
  the Word2000.Pas import unit for MS Word clearly does.  So, the code below picks up
  the Range object contained in the vRange variant and calls Set_Text on that.  This works
  but means that you need to add Word2000.Pas (or one of the more recent Word import
  units) to the Uses clause.

Note that I removed the call to GetActiveOle object to avoid an exception being
raised when it failed, which disrupted debugging.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Clipboard:TClipboard;
  WordApp,
  WordDocument: OleVariant;
  vRange : OleVariant;
  iRange : Range;  //  or WordRange for D10.3.1+
begin
  try
    WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application') ;
    WordApp.visible := true;
    WordApp.DisplayAlerts := False;

    try
      WordDocument := WordApp.Documents.Open('D:\aaad7\aaaofficeauto\test.pdf', ConfirmConversions := False); //, true, false);

      vRange := WordDocument.range;
      Label1.Caption := IntToStr(vRange.Start) + ':' + IntToStr(vRange.End);
      vRange.copy;

      sleep(1000);//Otherwise it fails
      RichEdit1.Clear;
      RichEdit1.PasteFromClipboard;

      //  vRange.Set_Text(' ');  // This provokes a "Method Set_Text not supported by automation object" exception
      //  SO ...
      //  Pick up the Range interface contained in the vRange variant
      iRange := IDispatch(WordDocument.range) as Range;
      // and call Set_Text on it to set the Range's text to a single space
      iRange.Set_Text(' ');
      //  Clear the iRange interface
      iRange := Nil;

      finally
        //   beware that the following discards and changes to the .Pdf
        //   so if you want to save any changes, you should do it
        //   before calling iRange.Set_Text
        WordDocument.close(False, False, False);
        WordDocument := UnAssigned;
      end;
  finally
    WordApp.Quit(False, False, False);
    WordApp := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Tested with MS Word 2010 on Windows 10 64-bit/

Comment: When I close document there is another dialog:

Do you want to keep the last item you copied?
If you do, it may take a bi longer to exit.

Is any way to say "no" without manual intervention?

Comment: I don't get the second dialog.  Maybe it's because of the size of your PDF.  Try calling ClipBoard.Clear after RichEdit1.PasteFromClipboard.  I will test it myself later.

Comment: Actually, calling Clipboard.Clear or Cancel produces an AV, so I would try reducing the size of WordDocument.range and then calling range.copy agin to reduce the size of what's on the clipboard.

Comment: Is any way interact with that dialog?

Comment: I've found something which **seems** to avoid the dialog, but it needs some testing and simplification.  I'll try to post an update tomorrow.

Comment: When I try Clipboard.Clear, MS Word gives an error "Access violation at address 0062C105 in module 'MSWORD.exe'. Read of address 00000000"

Comment: Yes, I got that, too.  But see my update, which shows a way to avoid getting the prompt about the Clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Word2000 was included in uses clause, but "Range" is not recognized at var declaration "iRange : Range";

Comment: Sounds impossible unless you have a faulty Word2000.Pas.  Open it and go to around line 7051:  It should say `  Range = interface(IDispatch)'. If ot dosn't, try text-searching for it.   I've been using Word2000.Pas for years and have never had Range not being recognised so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: The problem was that our Word2000.pas are different. I am using Delphi 10.3.1 and it might be the reason. Instead of  Range = interface(IDispatch) my Word2000.pas has   WordRange = interface(IDispatch) at line 6981. So I changed declaration to "  iRange : WordRange;" and now it works well. Many Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering: Is any way to skip sleep(1000)? Now I need to increase it to sleep(3000) to process my file.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, because it works fine for me even with the Sleep commented out, though the form does not update until the procedure has finished. What happens for you without Sleep()?

Comment: I get error message "Call was rejected by callee".

vRange.copy takes time, and while it copies text, calling      RichEdit1.PasteFromClipboard rises an error

Comment: >Tested with MS Word 2010 — Microsoft Word 2010 works with PDF? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
procedure TFWordAnalyzer.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Clipboard:TClipboard;
WordApp,
WordDocument: OleVariant;
vRange : OleVariant;
iRange : WordRange;

begin

try
WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application') ;
WordApp.visible := true;
WordApp.DisplayAlerts := False;

try
  WordDocument := WordApp.Documents.Open('D:\Corpus\Adyg\Hudmir.pdf', ConfirmConversions := False); //, true, false);

  vRange := WordDocument.range;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(vRange.Start) + ':' + IntToStr(vRange.End);
  vRange.copy;

  sleep(1000);//Otherwise it fails
  RichEdit1.Clear;
  RichEdit1.PasteFromClipboard;
  iRange := IDispatch(WordDocument.range) as WordRange;
  iRange.Set_Text(' ');
  iRange := Nil;

  finally

    WordDocument.close(False, False, False);
    WordDocument := UnAssigned;
  end;
 finally
   WordApp.Quit(False, False, False);
   WordApp := Unassigned;

 end;

  end;
```